# problema de sincronia al hacer un insertMany con nodejs y mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy intentando ejecutar varias funciones en un orden especifico,
sucede que yo retorno un un valor ok true si todo fue bien o un valor ok false si hubo algun error. Abajo en el codigo cuando invoco la funcion guardo el resultado en una variable `saving` y verifico si el ok es false o no, pero sucede que hago console log saving esta llegando con un valor true, lo que no deberia ser porque yo mismo estoy provocando el error para poder hacer esta validacion.
Basicamente lo que quiero que estas funciones se ejecuten de manera asincrona, tambien el contenido de estas. Es decir, que no se ejecute `saveRoles` si no ha terminado `saveLanguages` para de esta manera yo poder aplicar la validacion de saving.
Este es el codigo:

```
exports.start = (req, res) => {

function saveLanguages() {
    try{
        let documents = Object.keys(languages).map( key => {
            return new Language({
                abbreviation: key,
                name: languages[key].name,
                native_name: languages[key].nativeName
            });
        });
        Language.insertMany(documents, (errors, insertedLanguages) => {
            if(errors) {
                return {
                    ok: false,
                    errors
                };
            }
        });
        // if everythingh is ok
        return {
            ok: true
        };
    }catch(errors){
        return {
            ok: false,
            errors
        };
    }
}

function saveRoles() {
    try{
        let documents = Object.keys(roles).map( key => {
            return new Role({
                name: roles[key].name,
                description: roles[key].description
            });
        });
        Role.insertMany(documents, (errors, insertedRoles) => {
            if(errors) {
                return {
                    ok: false,
                    errors
                };
            }
        });
        // if everythingh is ok
        return {
            ok: true
        };
    }catch(errors){
        return {
            ok: false,
            errors
        };
    }
}

function savePaymentMethods() {
    try{
        let documents = Object.keys(paymentMethods).map( key => {
            return new Role({
                name: paymentMethods[key].name,
                description: paymentMethods[key].description
            });
        });
        PaymentMethod.insertMany(documents, (errors, insertedPaymentMethods) => {
            if(errors) {
                return {
                    ok: false,
                    errors
                };
            }
        });
        // if everythingh is ok
        return {
            ok: true
        };
    }catch(errors){
        return {
            ok: false,
            errors
        };
    }
}

saving = saveLanguages();
console.log(saving);
if(saving.ok === false) return res.status(400).json({ok: false, errors});
saving = saveRoles();
if(saving.ok === false) return res.status(400).json({ok: false, errors});
saving = savePaymentMethods();
if(saving.ok === false) return res.status(400).json({ok: false, errors});
// if everything was saved fine
return res.status(200).json({
    ok: true
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Nuevamente el problema es de asincronía (siempre lo es). Pero más allá de ese problema, lo que sucede es que estás mezclando el concepto de llamadas a procesos asíncronos usando funciones `callback` y pretendiendo que las mismas devuelvan un resultado al ámbito en el que fueron llamadas dichas funciones.

El resultado es que nunca obtendrás los resultados en dichos ámbitos, ya que el resultado de las operaciones asíncronas siempre vivirán dentro de la función `callback` y nunca podrás sacarlo de ellas, a menos que todo tu proceso sea de tipo `async` y utlices `await` (sin usar ya las `callback`) para esperar por los resultados asíncronos.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Antes de intentar responder tu pregunta, vamos a tratar de mostrar un par de ejemplos sobre el uso de funciones `callback` y los procesos asíncronos.

Vamos a crear una función que puede devolver una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) o que recibe una [función `callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Nuestra función:

```js
function miProcesoAsincrono(algunArgumento, callback) {
  let error = !algunArgumento ?
    new ReferenceError('Falta algún argumento') :
    (isNaN(algunArgumento) ? new TypeError('Argumento no numérico') : null );

  if(callback && {}.toString.call(callback) === '[object Function]') {
    // hemos pasado una función callback como último argumento
    // el siguiente 'setTimeout' simula un proceso asíncrono
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(error) {
        return callback(error, null);
       }
      const resultado = algunArgumento * 2;
      return callback(null, resultado);
    }, 0);
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(error) {
      return reject(error);
    }
    const resultado = algunArgumento * 2;
    return resolve(resultado);
  });
}

let usandoPromesa = miProcesoAsincrono(3);
console.log(usandoPromesa); // {} (se muestra primero)
usandoPromesa
.then(result => {
  console.log(result); // 6 (se muestra tercero)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error.message);
});

let usandoCallback = miProcesoAsincrono(6, (error, result) => {
  console.log(result); // 12 (se muestra último)
});
console.log(usandoCallback); // {} (se muestra segundo)

(async () => {
  //ámbito async autoejecutado
  try {
    let usandoPromesa = await miProcesoAsincrono(4);
    console.log(usandoPromesa); // 8 (se muestra 4to)
    let usandoCallback = miProcesoAsincrono('cadena', (error, result) => {
      if(error) {
        throw error; // lanzará una excepción
      }
      return result;
    });
    console.log(usandoCallback); // {} (se muestra 5to)
    let usandoAwaitConCallback = miProcesoAsincrono(10, (error, result) => {
      if(error) {
        throw error; // lanzará una excepción
      }
      return result;
    });
    console.log(usandoAwaitConCallback); // {} (se muestra 6to)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

No nos detengamos a ver la lógica expuesta, sólo analicemos la implementación. Tenemos una función que puede recibir 2 argumentos, si el segundo argumento es una función `callback` se ejecutará la misma, para operar con el primer argumento, pero si no se pasa una función `callback`, se devuelve una Promesa.

Lo importante aquí es la salida de cada llamado a la función asíncrona. En el caso del uso de Promesas, el valor devuelto por la misma sólo estará disponible en el método `then()` o si la misma es llamada con `await` en un entorno `async`.

Cuando no se usa una Promesa sino que se usa una función `callback`. el resultado sólo estará disponible dentro de la función `callback`, aunque use la sentencia `return` dentro de la misma para devolver el resultado. Ahora, si uso `await` en combinación con `callback` obtengo un resultado indefinido, ya que si bien estoy usando `return` en la función `callback`, el proceso al ser asíncrono y no devolver una Promesa, no recibe nunca el resultado que vive sólo dentro de la función `callback`.

Para el caso de tu pregunta en particular, tenemos que el método que utilizas: [`insertMany()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) devuelve una Promesa si no pasas o usas una función `callback`, pero devuelve `undefined` si pasas una función `callback` como lo haces actualmente.

Lo que debes hacer es cambiar la lógica de tu aplicación para que sea coherente con lo que esperas como resultado. Es decir, si vas a esperar por el resultado de las 3 funciones, puedes usar funciones `callback` pero debes llamarlas en cascada, es decir, hacer el llamado de una función uno dentro del otro en las funciones `callback`.

**Usando `callback`**

El código que tienes actualmente lo puedes reescribir de la siguiente forma para usar las funciones `callback`:

```js
exports.start = (req, res) => {
  function saveLanguages() {
    let documents = Object.keys(languages).map( key => {
      return new Language({
        abbreviation: key,
        name: languages[key].name,
        native_name: languages[key].nativeName
      });
    });
    Language.insertMany(documents, (errors, insertedLanguages) => {
      if(errors) {
        return res.status(400).json({ok: false, errors});
      }
      // si todo estuvo bien procedemos a salvar lo siguiente
      saveRoles();
    });
  }

  function saveRoles() {
    let documents = Object.keys(roles).map( key => {
      return new Role({
        name: roles[key].name,
        description: roles[key].description
      });
    });
    Role.insertMany(documents, (errors, insertedRoles) => {
      if(errors) {
        return res.status(400).json({ok: false, errors});
      }
      // si todo está OK procedemos a llamar a la última función
    });
    savePaymentMethods();
  }

  function savePaymentMethods() {
    // esta es la última función llamada, asi que aquí debemos devolver un resultado global al cliente
    let documents = Object.keys(paymentMethods).map( key => {
      return new Role({
        name: paymentMethods[key].name,
        description: paymentMethods[key].description
      });
    });
    PaymentMethod.insertMany(documents, (errors, insertedPaymentMethods) => {
      if(errors) {
        return res.status(400).json({ok: false, errors});
      }
      // Si todo está OK ya podemos retornar el resultado final al cliente
      return res.status(200).json({
        ok: true
      });
    });  
  }

  // ahora iniciamos el ciclo:
  saveLanguages();
}
```

Ahora, si bien esta aproximación puede funcionar, hay problema muy particular con la forma en que tienes escrito todo este *middleware*, pero eso sería desviarnos mucho de la pregunta original. Tal como tienes esto, estás asignando a una sola función llamada `start` la responsabilidad de 3 cosas totalmente diferentes. Por otro lado, si la segunda inserción falla, la primera queda hecha, y si los datos son relacionados, vas a tener inconsistencia de los mismos en tu base de datos.

**Usando `async / await`**

Otra forma para evitar el anidamiento de llamadas en las funciones `callback` es usar un entorno `async` y la sentencia `await`, por ejemplo:

```js
exports.start = async (req, res) => { // entorno async

  function saveLanguages() {
    let documents = Object.keys(languages).map( key => {
      return new Language({
        abbreviation: key,
        name: languages[key].name,
        native_name: languages[key].nativeName
      });
    });
    return Language.insertMany(documents); // devuelve una Promesa
  }

  function saveRoles() {
    let documents = Object.keys(roles).map( key => {
      return new Role({
        name: roles[key].name,
        description: roles[key].description
      });
    });
    return Role.insertMany(documents); // devuelve una Promesa
  }

  function savePaymentMethods() {
    let documents = Object.keys(paymentMethods).map( key => {
      return new Role({
        name: paymentMethods[key].name,
        description: paymentMethods[key].description
      });
    });
    return PaymentMethod.insertMany(documents); // devuelve una Promesa
  }

  try {
    // en las siguientes llamadas no almaceno el resultado porque no lo enviarás
    // al cliente, por lo que se ve en tu código, pero podría guardarlo así:
    // let savedLanguages = await saveLanguages();

    await saveLanguages();
    await saveRoles();
    await savePaymentMethods();
    // si llegamos hasta aquí es que todo fue OK
    return res.status(200).json({
      ok: true
    });
  } catch(errors) {
    // aquí se captura algún error ocurrido en alguna de las 3 funciones
    return res.status(400).json({ok: false, errors});
  }
}
```

De esta forma el código se ve más limpio, aunque vuelvo a insistir que no es la forma correcta de realizar este tipo de transacciones.

Espero que esto te oriente y te ayude a resolver el problema.